# From Adonijah's self-exaltation to self-debasement at the horns of the altar, what was the time frame?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, king-david, melachim-kings-book-of, parashat-chaye-sara

From Adonijah's self-exaltation to self-debasement at the horns of the altar, what was the time frame?

From the time
"Adonijah the son of Haggith exalted himself, saying: 'I will be king'" (1 Kings Chapter 1:5)
to the time
"Adonijah feared because of Solomon; and he arose, and went, and caught hold on the horns of the altar" (1 Kings Chapter 1:50),
how long was it, what was the time frame?

Comment: At least his feast and his downfall occurred on the same day? Verse 41. Adonijah and all the guests who were with him heard it as they were finishing their feast. On hearing the sound of the trumpet, Joab asked, “What’s the meaning of all the noise in the city?” etc.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE, yes, I can see that. As soon as I read, your words "feast and his downfall occurred on the same day", my mind rushed to a different but similar event, that of Esther's "feast and his [Haman's] downfall [that] occurred on the same day".

Comment: See https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.166?lang=bi מפני מה נהרג אדוניה בן חגית מפני שתבע באבישג השונמית, אמר לו עילה היו מבקשים להתיר דמן של בעלי מחלוקת: Why was Adoniyahu killed? Because he asked Avishag to be intimate with him. Others said, that was just as excuse and the real reason was because he was a disputatious man. So you would have to know when he solicited Avishag to get a better grasp of the timeframe.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE The episode with Avishag happened after he grasped the horns of the altar.

Comment: @Meir yes, on plain reading, that is true, that the episode with Avishag happened after he grasped the horns of the altar," but then sometimes, there just might be a rabbinic authority that might say that the way it is written is not in a chronological way.

Comment: @ninamag They do so when there's a logical reason to argue that it's out of order, not just arbitrarily. (And furthermore, the Gemara, Pesachim 6b, says that only when the two passages are about different topics can we say that they might be out of chronological order.)